# Returning an Array from a generic class

Tags: java

I get a `ClassCastException` error when I run this because of the implicit cast of d to a double when I run the code. However, if I change reference to d in to `Object[]` then it can't be a parameter to the set function. If I change the set function to accept an `Object[]` then everything works fine, but then the class will fail at runtime if anyone calls set on an object that isn't of type `N`.

I need a solution that can `get()` the old array (or a clone thereof) and that can `set()` data to a new array.

```
public class Foo<N> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Double> foo = new Foo<Double>();
        Double[] d = foo.get();

        // do stuff to d ...

        foo.set(d);
    }

    N[] data;

    public Foo() {
        data = (N[]) new Object[2];
    }

    public N[] get() {
        return (N[]) data;
    }

    public void set(N[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that q.

Comment: you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3403976/2513573 to extract the type and Array.newInstance to create the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array with the right runtime type requires some kind of runtime representation of that type. A generic class like `Foo<N>` has no runtime representation of `N`.

There are two solutions:

1. Use a `List<N>` instead. This is best if it is possible!
2. Manually add a runtime representation of `N` by passing in a `Class<N>` to `Foo`, use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance` to create the array.

Code for the second solution:

```
public Foo(Class<N> newDataClass) {
    data = (N[]) Array.newInstance(newDataClass, 2);
}

Foo<Double> foo = new Foo<>(Double.class);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If what you want to do is instead to get a copy of an existing `Double` array you can do that with `(N[]) data.clone()`. Setting it will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick to this.

```
class Foo<N> {

    // Deliberately no parameters.
    N[] myArray = makeArray();

    private N[] makeArray(N... ns) {
        return ns;
    }

    public N[] get() {
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

This may look like there is no casting (which is a good thing) but actually there is, it is just being done by the `varargs` system.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear w the question but in my case the array is already instantiated and I need to make a change to it. So I need to get it from foo do something to it. And reset it. I can't have a solution that instantiates it in the constructer.

Comment: @avisnacks: In your example you create the array in the `Foo` constructor. Is that not how it should work? Can you update the question to make that clearer?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: This does not work. You will always get an `Object` array in `myArray`. When the initialiser calls `makeArray` there is no trace of `N` left, it has been erased. Generic vararg method always creates `Object` arrays. It is not possible to create arrays of a generic type at all. That is described for example in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays).

Comment: @Lii - After erasure **all** arrays are `Object[]`. This *trick* merely avoids casting.

Comment: Okay, it seems like I misunderstood the purpose, sorry.  *"After erasure all arrays are `Object[]`"* I'm not sure what you mean here. All arrays of a *generic type* will be `Object[]` at runtime. But not the other ones, `Double[]` and `double[]` will have those runtime types. Erasure is only concerned with generic types.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient (but verbose) way to do this would be to change the constructor to take a dummy argument with the array type, since you know that it is double at your main method.

```
  public class Foo<N> {
         N[] data;

         public Foo(N inType) {
             data = (N[]) Array.newInstance(inType.getClass(), 2) ;
         }

         public N[] get() {
             return (N[]) data;
         }

         public void set(N[] data) {
             this.data = data;
         }

         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Foo<Double> foo = new Foo<Double>(new Double(0));
             Double[] d = foo.get();
             // do stuff to d ...
             foo.set(d);
         }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a generic is, that it does not have any specific type at runtime. It's just the class `Object`, which means, that creating such object is completely pointless, because you would, in fact, just create an object of type `Object`.

You can however create such objects from outside of the class, because the real type of the object is known here (`Double`). Thus I would suggest to use some sort of `List`, which can be dynamic, to store the values.